# How to generate a csv without adding to a table in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

im currently generating a csv file througha php script, this happens after a chain of events as i have shown below

[image]

but now i have a requirement to generate the csv without adding it to a table, first of all is it possible?? if so can you please assist me on this

my php code to add to table

```
    <?php

$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'bookers' AND table_name LIKE 'b_table_%' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($table_count)){

$table = $row["TABLE_NAME"];

$query = ("CALL Dummy_2('{$table}')");
$excute = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

the dummy_2 sp

```
BEGIN   

SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("INSERT INTO report(ID, name, accountname, accountID, status, count, earliest_booking,recent_booking)
SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, name, c.ID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
FROM    ",b_table," a INNER JOIN bookers b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID

WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR)
GROUP BY ID;");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END$$
```

my php code to generate csv

```
require 'exportcsv.inc.php';

$table="report"; // this is the tablename that you want to export to csv from mysql.

exportMysqlToCsv($table);
```

can put the exportcsv.inc.php too if needed

**P.S - Is there a possibility where i could create a temporary table and insert the data to the csv**

Comment: Inside the file exportcsv.inc.php, there's some code written in PHP which does an SQL query, takes the data from MySQL and then exports it to CSV. **Yes of course you can write code which outputs CSV while skipping the SQL part, taking the data from elsewhere.** You just need to write the appropriate PHP code to do so.

Comment: thank you ill go through that and let you knw

Comment: i saw that :D.. btw if u r an sql expert is there a possibility where i could create a temporary table and insert the data to the csv

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data directly into a csv file. You just take a array and insert your data into this array. After adding the data into that array, you have to need to run a loop which put the data from the array to csv using file handling concept.

Here  is a sample code which help you to understand the concept.

```
<?php

$list = array
(
"Peter,Griffin,Oslo,Norway",
"Glenn,Quagmire,Oslo,Norway",
);

$file = fopen("contacts.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
    {
    fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
    }

fclose($file); 

?>
```